# SOQL Like Query?

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl

I am trying to make a query that will search for accounts with a name similar or exactly matching a field value.

So for example I have "Sales-Force" in the field. There is an account called "Salesforce" or "Sales Force"

My current query

```
Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Sales-Force%'
```

This isn't returning my accounts named "Sales Force" or "Salesforce" in my query editor.

UPDATED * My Apex code

```
string accountName= record.Name;
    if(accountName.contains('-'))
    {
        accountName = accountName.replace('-', '%');
    }
    if(accountName.contains(' '))
    {
        accountName = accountName.replace(' ', '%');
    }
    accountName= '%' + accountName+ '%';

List<Account> accountLookup = new List<Account>();
accountLookup = [Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :accountName];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Sales%Force%'
```

or:

```
String likeValue = '%Sales%Force%';

Account[] accounts = [Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :likeValue];
```

**PS**

Just noticed Oleksandr had posted this and deleted it: please clarify your question.

**PPS**

You could add some code that tries to generalize the pattern e.g. replaces non-alphabetic characters with a `%` and puts a `%` between each character. Or you could consider e.g. a [Metaphone](https://github.com/appirio-tech/apex-metaphone) approach to the matching.

Comment: I added the apex code im using to my op

Comment: Hello, i've added some logic to my apex code. I have it check if contains and replace with %. It work for spaces, but no hyphens however... I added it to my OP

Comment: @AlexanderAtkinsoon The method returns a new string with the replaced characters (it does not modify the string) so you need something more like `accountName = '%' + accountName.replace('-', '%').replace(' ', '%') + '%';`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, here's the LIKE [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?search_text=like)

> LIKE  Like    Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName
>   matches the characters of the text string in the specified value. The
>   LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL is similar to the LIKE operator in SQL;
>   it provides a mechanism for matching partial text strings and includes
>   support for wildcards.
>
> ```
> The % and _ wildcards are supported for the LIKE operator.
> The % wildcard matches zero or more characters.
> The _ wildcard matches exactly one character.
> The text string in the specified value must be enclosed in single quotes.
> The LIKE operator is supported for string fields only.
> The LIKE operator performs a case-insensitive match, unlike the case-sensitive matching in SQL.
> The LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL supports escaping of special characters % or _.
> Don’t use the backslash character in a search except to escape a special character.
> ```
>
> For example, the following query matches Appleton, Apple, and Appl,
>   but not Bap

So for your query `Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Sales-Force%'`, what you're asking for is all accounts with a name that contains 'Salesforce-Force', so that wouldn't match either accounts.

So to capture all of your examples you'd need this query
`SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Sales_Force' OR Name LIKE 'SalesForce'` which would match 'Sales-Force', 'Sales Force', 'SalesForce', or 'sAlEsFoRcE' (like is case-insensitive)

Comment: What if the name is a variable and not hardcoded?

Comment: works just fine, you can actually pass in a array of stuff ie. `LIKE :values` where values is array with `('val1%', '%val1','other%vals')`

Comment: not the array only works with bind variables

Comment: and of course there is dynamic soql that let's you do it all dynamically

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it. It is not possible to use value of a field in condition expression, as a value.

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm?search_text=%25)

> fieldExpression uses the following syntax:
>
> **fieldName comparisonOperator value**

---

> A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a
>   value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field.
>   You must supply a native value—**other field names or calculations are
>   not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for
>   dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an
>   error.

**update**

looks like it is XY problem, and I am sure desired result could be achieved by means of formula fields and other tools. Maybe you can post source of this question?

Comment: My question comes from a trigger i've created that checks a text field and searches a record based on its value. A lookup field is filled with the ID of the record found. I've been asked to make sure it checks for variations. Incase someone puts a hyphen in the name instead of a space for example it will still find the record.

Comment: I guess in short my question comes down to, is it possible to make queries typo-proof?

Comment: now this question is fully understandable and as for me  @KeithC  gave a nice answer